# AWS RDS Parameter Group not changing MySQL encoding

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am running a MySQL database on RDS. I want to change all of my encodings to `utf8mb4`. I created a parameter group on RDS with all `character_set_*` parameters as `utf8mb4`, assigned it to my RDS instance, and then rebooted the instance. However, when I run `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%char%'` on my DB, there are still values of `latin1`, which I do not want:

```
character_set_client        latin1
character_set_connection    latin1
character_set_database      utf8mb4
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results       latin1
character_set_server        utf8mb4
character_set_system        utf8
character_sets_dir          /rdsdbbin/mysql-5.6.22.R1/share/charsets/
```

Likewise, new columns that I create on the DB are `latin1` encoded instead of `utf8mb4` encoded. I can change the encoding values manually through the `mysql` command line, but this doesn't help since the values are also reset to `latin1` when I push to production.

Answer (score 8):

I think this the issue is the distinction between **VARIABLES** and **GLOBAL VARIABLES**.

If you list the **GLOBAL VARIABLES** this should reflect what you see in your parameter group: (assuming you've rebooted as Naveen suggested in the other answer)

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';
```

---

This is opposed to what you see in your regular **VARIABLES**:

```
SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';
```

These can sometimes be overridden by the options supplied in the connection. eg connecting using the options **--default-character-set**:

```
mysql -h YOUR_RDS.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -P 3306 --default-character-set=utf8 -u YOUR_USERNAME -p
```

Answer (score 3):

After changing the parameter group - do you the warning "Pending Reboot" in the console. If yes, try rebooting the DB Instance and the new character set would start be applied.

More information - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithParamGroups.html

[image]

Comment: Yes, after I applied the parameter group, I waited until I saw the `pending-reboot` in the console. Then, I rebooted the RDS instance. The character set was not applied correctly.

Comment: Please contact AWS support or take a snapshot and restore it again.

Comment: I have the same issue and, still looking for a solution!

Comment: I have the same issue